# Replace "." with "," in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, format

I have an Excel file, generated from database. It contains a column filled with number values that looks like this:

```
Values:
123,17
1973,27
12124.97
123.09
-234,01
-732.66
```

My problem is, that Excel finds numbers only when they are used with "," separator. How can I change all the "." to ",", so all values in that column would be recognized as numbers (aligned to right side of column).

Also, I have a lot of those files to maintain, so an automatic procedure would be highly appriciated.

Comment: What's wrong with find and replace? Actually, are decimal points are different than commas?

Answer (score 1):

Select the Column and Hit CRTL+H,
Enter '.' in 'Find What' and enter ',' in 'Replace with' and hit 'Replace All' button

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but I'm looking for a better way. Multiple files with multiple columns like this are taking too much time to change using this method.

Comment: If it is for a Single Workbook, you can do the same in a single click by selecting entire work book in options button of the 'Find and Replace' window. But if you want to do this for multiple workbooks, then probably you may have to do  by macros.

Answer (score 1):

Your data sample looks wrong. It's inconsistent.

If your system uses the comma as the decimal separator, then ALL your numbers should use the comma for the decimal.

If your database system uses a dot as the decimal separator, then ALL your numbers should use the dot for the decimal.

The numbers in your example are a random mix of comma and dot as the decimal separator.

You may want to configure your source system to apply the decimal separator in a consistent way.

It's quite inconceivable why your system would use a comma for one value, but use a dot for another value. You may need to get to the bottom of that logic before you can proceed any further.

Possibly, the "numbers" are really text values from other data sources that use either comma or dot for the decimal separator.

Comment: It's not dependant on me, some people who Input data to database use dot, others use comma. Database doesn't check if values are consistent.

Comment: Well, that looks like a HUGE design flaw in the database.  In that case just use find and replace in Excel.